# Styling a Header for Javascript-Activated Headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, sections

So for my website I've successfully divided information sections, where in-page content can be variated. The only problem is that now I cannot see which header's content is activated.

here is the **[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/dtZLU/5/)** for it, and what i'm trying is for the selected header to be highlighted when the respective content is displayed.

The First Javascript code:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
    for (var i = 0; i < infoBox.length; i++) {
        infoBox[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery :-

```
   $(".heading").click(function(){    
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(".heading").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }   
    });
```

Update CSS with :

```
.active{
    color:red:
    border-bottom: 2px #7D5B61 solid !important;
}
```

and HTML with

```
<a class="heading active" onclick="toggle_visibility('info1');">
```

Js Fiddle Here : - http://jsfiddle.net/codenathan/dtZLU/8/

Comment: this is almost exactly what i want. but how do i get the border-bottom to change color as well to 2px #7D5B61 solid? I tried experimenting with the class .active, but it seems only to work on the color :/

Comment: Thats because on .infoWrapper .infoHead .heading css section is overriding the border-color so if you include !important it will ensure that one is being used. I have updated the answer for you http://jsfiddle.net/codenathan/dtZLU/15/

Comment: thank you so much! I've been stuck on that for a LONGGG time :D